# mySQL INSERT and SELECT query for embedded data sets

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by

I am trying to write an efficient mySQL INSERT query with this JSON data (converted to JSON for clarity):

```
[
    {
        "job": "Avocado Books Binding",
        "tasks": [
            "Finish collating the signatures",
            "Fix perfect binders",
            "Fold signatures"
        ]
    },
    {
        "job": "Prepress Workflow Development",
        "tasks": [
            "Research new proofing machines",
            "Find free proofing software"
        ]
    }
]
```

The resulting table structure would be (with this data)

```
Table: Jobs
job_id   job_title
1        Avocado Books Binding
2        Prepress Workflow Development

Table: Tasks
task_id   task_description                    job_id
1         Finish collating the signatures     1
2         Fix perfect binders                 1
3         Fold signatures                     1
4         Research new proofing machines      2
5         Find free proofing software         2
```

Where the Jobs and Tasks are associated by job_id.

I am also trying to write a SELECT query to obtain this data in a manner that it is efficient as well.

**Any help, references, or suggestions is greatly appreciated.**

UPDATE:

**Structure as a PHP Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [job] => Avocado Books Binding
            [tasks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Finish collating the signatures
                    [1] => Fix perfect binders
                    [2] => Fold signatures
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [job] => Avocado Books Binding
            [tasks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Finish collating the signatures
                    [1] => Fix perfect binders
                    [2] => Fold signatures
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*efficient*"?  Execution time?  Memory required?  Quantity/clarity of code?  ...?  If the data structure has only been converted to JSON "*for clarity*", in what form does it actually exist?

Comment: Efficient, considering execution time and the memory required. It exists as a PHP array

Comment: Could you be more specific?  How is the data structured within the array?

Comment: I have added the PHP array version of the data. I am sending the data as JSON to then server, but encoded as a PHP array it looks like the structure I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable PDO's prepared statement emulation, then repeatedly executing such (server-side prepared) statements will be much more efficient than multiple unprepared statements:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);

$insert_job = $dbh->prepare('
  INSERT INTO Jobs (job_title) VALUES (?)
');

$insert_task = $dbh->prepare('
  INSERT INTO Tasks (task_description, job_id) VALUES (:desc, :id)
');

$insert_task->bindParam(':desc', $task  , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_task->bindParam(':id',   $job_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

foreach (json_decode($json, TRUE) as $job) {
  $insert_job->execute([$job['job']]);
  $job_id = $insert_job->lastInsertId();
  foreach ($job['tasks'] as $task) $insert_task->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT j.job_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.task_description) task 
FROM jobs j 
INNER JOIN tasks ON j.job_id = t.job_id 
GROUP BY j.job_id;
```

Comment: If you could, an explanation of why this works possibly? I am not just looking for a copy-and-paste solution

Comment: This will give you the task description with comma separated values by job id

Comment: This will break if any task description contains a comma, as you won't be able to restore the original splitting. You can change the separator for `group_concat`, but that only modifies the problem. You might be better off iterating over the rows one at a time in a reasonable order. SQL simply isn't made for nested structures.